# Why don't operators downstream from Completable (andThen) run?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

Why don't operators below `andThen` get called? I have narrowed down the issue to the difference between using `andThen` (converting from Completable) to just using Single.

**Doesn't work**

```kotlin
import io.reactivex.Completable
import io.reactivex.Single

Completable.complete() // or in my case, heavyProcessWhichReturnsCompletable()
        .andThen { println("SUCCESS") } // This runs, but nothing after it
        .andThen { println("FAILURE") } // doesn't print
        .toSingle { "FAILURE" }.subscribe { it ->
            print("Result: $it") // doesn't print
        }
```

**Works:**

```kotlin
Single.just("SUCCESS").subscribe { it ->
    print("Result: $it") // prints!
}
```

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/5551 which was apparently originally asked here and then deleted. Maybe enough basis for an answer from someone who understands it properly. :)

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP, that's an interesting github issue. It looks like `doOnComplete` doesn't have this problem, but that is actually not a good alternative, as it will spoil the ordering of downstream operators (the `doOnComplete` will be called after the downstream operators).

Comment: It doesn't work because the curly brace creates an improper `CompletableSource` implementation. You need `andThen(Completable.fromAction { println("SUCCESS") } )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @akarnokd for explaining the issue. Naively, I was going to blame RxJava for this, but didn't want to turn into [this man](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=26192025) so I thought about it a bit more. It's my obligation to understand the code I write . [This](https://medium.com/android-news/kotlin-and-rx2-how-i-wasted-5-hours-because-of-wrong-brackets-581021717774) blog post was also instrumental in my understanding.

---

It is because `andThen` takes a `CompletableSource` argument, but using a lambda (curly braces) with no arguments causes the Completable to live *forever* (the completable never completes). So no future code (downstream operators) runs. `Completable` implements `CompletableSource`, so the **first** println runs, but not the second:

```kotlin
Completable.complete()
    .andThen(Completable.complete())
    .andThen {println("runs") } // runs
    .andThen {println("doesn't run") } // doesn't run
    .subscribe()
```

So above, I was able to use andThen twice successfully. The reason is `Completable.complete()` was a good `CompletableSource`, but println

I've written some explanations in each print statement as to why they run/ don't:

```kotlin
Completable.complete() // or in my case, heavyProcessWhichReturnsCompletable()
        .andThen (Completable.fromAction {println("SUCCESS")})
        .andThen {it ->
            println("Success, because fromAction succeeds after the code runs if no exception are raised")
            it.onComplete()
        }
        .andThen { println("Success, because the previous completable completed")}
        .andThen { println("Won't print here, because the previous one didn't complete"}
        .subscribe()
```

---

### Warning: This won't run.

```kotlin
Completable.complete()
    .andThen { Completable.complete() } // won't complete, because the first parameter is not called!
    .andThen { println("Failure") } // Won't complete
    .toSingle { println("Failure") }
    .subscribe()
```

**Fix** use either paranthesis **or** call `onComplete`:

```kotlin
Completable.complete()
        .andThen (Completable.complete()) // Completes
        .andThen { println("Success"); it.onComplete()  } // Completes
        .toSingle { println("Success") }
        .subscribe()
```